# Deep python dictionary recursion

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree, recursive-datastructures

I have a python dictionary:

```py
d = {
    "config": {
        "application": {
            "payment": {
                "dev": {
                    "modes": {"credit,debit,emi": {}},
                    "company": {
                        "address": {
                            "city": {"London": {}},
                            "pincode": {"LD568162": {}},
                        },
                        "country": {"United Kingdom": {}},
                        "phone": {"7865432765": {}},
                    },
                    "levels": {"0,1,2": {}},
                },
                "prod": {"modes": {"credit,debit": {}}, "levels": {"0,1": {}}},
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change it to something like this(if the value is empty{} then make the key as value for its parent)

```py
d = {
    "config": {
        "application": {
            "payment": {
                "dev": {
                    "modes": "credit,debit,emi",
                    "company": {
                        "address": {
                            "city": "London", 
                            "pincode": "LD568162"
                        },
                        "country": "United Kingdom",
                        "phone": "7865432765"
                    },
                    "levels": "0,1,2"
                }, 
                "prod": {
                    "modes": "credit,debit",
                    "levels": "0,1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

i tried to write the code to traverse this deep dictionary, but couldn't modify it to get the above output. Please help.

```py
def recur(json_object):
    for x in list(json_object.items()):
        print(x)
        recur(json_object[x])

d={'config': {'application': {'payment': {'dev': {'modes': {'credit,debit,emi': {}}, 'company': {'address': {'city': {'London': {}}, 'pincode': {'LD568162': {}}}, 'country': {'United Kingdom': {}}, 'phone': {'7865432765': {}}}, 'levels': {'0,1,2': {}}}, 'prod': {'modes': {'credit,debit': {}}, 'levels': {'0,1': {}}}}}}}
```

Comment: I updated my answer including another option with the recursive approach as in what you were originally doing. Hope you can get something from it too. If it's all the answer you need, you can accept it as the answer :)

Comment: thanks a lot @NielGodfreyPonciano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1

We can use a non-recursive approach with queues to enqueue each inner/nested element of the document and put as value if the nested value is just `{}`:

```
# d = ...

queue = [d]

while queue:
    data = queue.pop()
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and list(value.values()) == [{}]:
            data[key] = list(value.keys())[0]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            queue.append(value)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{
    "config": {
        "application": {
            "payment": {
                "dev": {
                    "modes": "credit,debit,emi",
                    "company": {
                        "address": {
                            "city": "London",
                            "pincode": "LD568162"
                        },
                        "country": "United Kingdom",
                        "phone": "7865432765"
                    },
                    "levels": "0,1,2"
                },
                "prod": {
                    "modes": "credit,debit",
                    "levels": "0,1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Solution 2

Here's a recursive approach

```
# d = ...

def recur(data):
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict) and list(value.values()) == [{}]:
            data[key] = list(value.keys())[0]
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            recur(value)

recur(d)

print(d)
```

**Output**

- Same as Solution 1